# Editform without model and editcontext?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, razor, blazor

I have to create a edit template for the entire application and I want to use editform and input* blazor controls.

But I am not able to provide a model and field/properties since the edit form is consumed by a datarow.
So since the data is provided from the database for the entire application and the edit template is fed only the datarow for data to be edited how can i go about this?

Comment: Side note: DataRow is old tech, are you sure you want to keep using that?  Blazor works much easier with EF.

Comment: Can you convert the row to a `dynamic` instance and bind to that?

Comment: row to a dynamic instance?

Comment: @PeterMorris What do you refer to by "`dynamic` instance"?

Comment: I can't remember, it was too long ago, sorry

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to have a class and write methods that map it to and from the datarow.

Comment: yes that would be very convenient ... thank you.But i cannot do that for the entire application...any alternative if I want to use the editform?

Comment: There is no reason you can't do that for every type of row, that should be enough.

Comment: I am trying to convert the existing windows application to blazor web app maintaining the architecture .... we have templates for everything and screens are just added by supplying the datatable and the type of controls with existing base class methods ..... so trying to use the same architecture and use one edit template for all screens with different type of data.  even if i create classes for every table in my database that uses the application how can i make the edittemplate model generic when the properties differ?